# IOError: [Errno 25] Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have the following code to find the width of the console in Linux, which works in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.X:

```
def get_default_console_width():
   try:
      from shutil import get_terminal_size
      console_width, rows = shutil.get_terminal_size()
   except Exception:
      import termios, fcntl, struct, sys
      s = struct.pack('hh', 0, 0)
      x = fcntl.ioctl(sys.stdout.fileno(), termios.TIOCGWINSZ, s)
      rows, console_width = struct.unpack("hh", x)
   return console_width
```

In my test_something.py file I test some function that calls *get_default_console_width()* and it gives me this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 25] Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

I know there are some similar posts with the same issue, but I did not find anything that would help in this case.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like `stdout` has been redirected to something that isn't a console window.

Comment: How does the title relate to the IOError? Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: @tdelaney My bad, I put the wrong title accidentally. Changed it now.

Comment: This would happen if stdout isn't a terminal (e,g,, redirecting to a file or run as a subprocess and its a pipe). There are different terminal types, like physical terminal attached via a serial line, that may not accept that ioctl. But if this is a linux machine and its default terminal emulator, it should work. Just guesses here.

Answer (score 2):

This generally means something is capturing stdout (eg: pytest). In which case  `shutil.get_terminal_size().columns` will return `80`.

One option is to explicitly set columns via the environment variable `COLUMNS` of your process.

Comment: Doesn'T work in my case even if I do `os.environ['COLUMNS'] = '80'` in the beginning of the test.

Answer (score 1):

Most IDE's like **PyCharm** or **Wing** has simulated Terminals so running a code contain `get_terminal_size()` will trigger [`Errno 25] Inappropriate ioctl for device` because OS has no way of getting **rows** and **columns** of a Simulated Terminal inside a IDE.
Running the code in OS's native Terminal **solved** this problem for me.